# Help: When I call TransferFrom after approve function it will revert

Tags: solidity

when I call depositTokens() which calls transferFrom() It'll revert :

In react:

```
const stakeHandler = async (amount) => {
setLoading(true);
token.methods
  .approve(defiAddress, amount)
  .send({ from: account })
  .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
    defi.methods
      .depositTokens(amount)
      .send({ from: account })
      .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });
```

In DeFi.sol:

```
function depositTokens(uint256 _value) public payable {
require(_value > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
//Transfer tokens to this contract address for staking
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
//updating staing balance
stakingBalance[msg.sender] += _value;

if (!hasStaked[msg.sender]) {
  //updating stakers array
  stakers.push(msg.sender);
}
//updating staking status
isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
}
```

In Token.sol

```
function transferFrom(
address _from,address _to,uint256 _amount) public payable returns (bool success) {
require(balanceOf[_from] >= _amount, "Insufficient Token balance");
require(allowance[_from][msg.sender] >= _amount);
balanceOf[_from] -= _amount;
balanceOf[_to] += _amount;
allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _amount;
transfer(_to, _amount);
emit Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
return true;
}
```

[image]
[image]

You could find both contract(DeFi and Token) files and whole react in this github repository

Github:  [enter link description here](https://github.com/xolmer/Defi-Demo-1/tree/main/contracts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong constructor parameters.

DeFi [constructor](https://github.com/xolmer/Defi-Demo-1/blob/45551dbf0981884c50eeba3e7f6893e8c337806d/contracts/DeFi.sol#L19) -

```
constructor(Token _token, RWD _rwd) { ... }
```

Your [deployment](https://github.com/xolmer/Defi-Demo-1/blob/45551dbf0981884c50eeba3e7f6893e8c337806d/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js#L12) script -

```
await deployer.deploy(DeFi, rwd.address, token.address);
```

Switch rwd and token. This also explains the "strange" FRIED balance error.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate really appreciate it ,that worked